# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints in case of UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, icarousel

I am using iCarousel to implement a cover flow. I provide views to it in my iCarousel data source method, like this:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index   reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

    if(!view) {
        view = [[SDHotOnThumbView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,  kHotOnThumbViewWidth, kHotOnThumbViewHeight)];
        view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    }
    [((SDHotOnThumbView*)view) setData:[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:index]];
    return view;
}
```

The method setData apart from setting the label's text in SDHotOnThumbView instance, and starting image download for the image view in it, also makes a call to a method updateLabelLayoutWithAttributedText, which is implemented as under in the SDHotOnThumbView class:

```
-(void)updateLabelLayoutWithAttributedText:(NSMutableAttributedString*) labelString
{
    float height = [self heightOfAttributedText:labelString  width:self.frame.size.width];
    self.descriptionLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    //self.descriptionLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.frame.size.width;
    NSDictionary *viewsDict = @{@"desclabel":self.descriptionLabel};
    NSArray *constraintsH = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0- [desclabel]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict];
    [self addConstraints:constraintsH];
    NSArray *constraintsV = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:[desclabel(==%f)]-10-|", height]
                                                                options:0
                                                                metrics:nil
                                                                  views:viewsDict];
    [self addConstraints:constraintsV];

}
```

iCarousel recycles views, and I have to allocate a view if the recycled view is nil, and configure it every time the carousel asks for a view at a given index. Based on the size of an attributed string, I update vertical constraints for the label with the new height, in the second method I have attached, so that the label is resized as per the data it contains. The views layout just fine, except that I get . For example, I get

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.     Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2)  find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b82f330 V:[UILabel:0x7d861820'SanDisk Cruzer Blade USB  ...'(51.2)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7d862df0 V:[UILabel:0x7d861820'SanDisk Cruzer Blade USB ...'(65.6)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7d862df0 V:[UILabel:0x7d861820'SanDisk Cruzer Blade USB  ...'(65.6)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in  the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
<UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Logging computed heights for the label, I can see that probably when the cell is removed from the collection view and re-added for some different index in the collection view, it probably holds on to its old height, and tries to add a new vertical constraint, breaking the previous one. I even tried removing all label constraints from the view, and adding everytime set data is called, but i see the same happening in Xcode, even though everything seems to work as expected. How do I go about these Xcode warnings, or is it fine if the layout is as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you doubly inserted 2 different heights to the label, the first one's height is 51.2 and the second one is 65.6. Please check your code once more.

Comment: Yes..the height related constraint is added every time, as the method setData is called for every visible cell, causing a constraint with a new height to be added.

Comment: try removing the old constraint or remove the label: `[label removeFromSuperview]` before adding new constraint.